# WriteRegBinary is not working

Tags: registry, nsis

I'm trying to write a hexadecimal value with WriteRegBin, and it doesn't write anything, though returns 'ok' result:

```
WriteRegBin HKCU "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2" \
        "SettingsCheck" DEADBEEF01223211151
```

What's wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WriteRegBin HKCU "HKCU\..."` is not a valid registry path. I don't know if you have this in your real code or if there is something else going on. Remember to use `SetRegView` if you are working with 32/64 bit specific parts of the registry on a 64 bit system...

This works correctly for me:

```
Section
WriteRegBin HKCU "Software\Test" \
        "Dummy" DEADBEEF01223211151
SectionEnd
```